# Using ThreadLocal vs Atomic

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

According to `ThreadLocal`'s javadoc, it sounds like its a thread-specific container for 1+ atomic fields.

Is the purpose of `ThreadLocal` to represent all the atomic fields for a single `Thread`, or is it to just provided a convenience container when you have multiple `Atomic*` instances that need to be logically grouped together?

I guess I'm wondering why I would ever want to use a `ThreadLocal` instead of, say, an `AtomicLong` or `AtomicInteger`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of `ThreadLocal` is that the fields do *not* have to be atomic -- there is no need to synchronize their values with centralized memory.  They are thread-local and only exist in the threads local memory storage.

> Why would I ever want to use a ThreadLocal instead of, say, an AtomicLong or AtomicInteger?

`ThreadLocal` is very useful for storing a per-thread copy of something.  For example a `SimpleDateFormat` which is unfortunately not reentrant.

```
private final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> threadLocal =
        new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    }
};
...
// get one that is per-thread
DateFormat dateFormat = threadLocal.get();
```

This is a useful pattern because then we don't have to `synchronize` on it or worry about any `volatile` or other atomic operations that have memory barriers.

One caveat is that `ThreadLocal` variables often are detected as memory leaks since they are only freed when the thread is reaped which can cause problems with web container class loaders.

Comment: Thanks @Gray! So, if I have classes that aren't immutable, and I need to synchronize on their instances but do not want to have to get into all the java.util.concurrent.* "stuff", I can just protect them with `ThreadLocal`...is that a fair summary?!?

Comment: Yes @herpylderp (excellent username btw) as long as they can be local only to the thread.  Once the thread finishes, all of its `ThreadLocal` classes can be GC'd.  Immutable and non-reentrant classes as well -- although maybe non-rentrant are by definition not immutable.

Answer (score 3):

> I guess I'm wondering why I would ever want to use a ThreadLocal instead of, say, an AtomicLong or AtomicInteger?

They serve **completely** different purposes. `ThreadLocal` means you don't have to worry about synchronization by granting each thread its own copy of an object. Therefore, an object stored in a `ThreadLocal` cannot possibly be accessed by more than one thread.

`Atomic*` also mean that you don't have to worry about synchronization, but they are specifically meant to be shared across threads.

Comment: You *can* access an object stored in a `ThreadLocal` from other threads if you publish its reference elsewhere. More importantly, `AtomicReference` doesn't remove the need for synchronization on the object it references. It only provides safe publication of the reference between threads. Sticking an `ArrayList` into an `AtomicReference` won't make the `ArrayList` itself thread-safe.